# C++ Efficiently store Tile Map tiles

Tags: c++, sfml

I am making a TileMap based Game engine.

I have a "Tile" Class, this is used to define block types and set flags to determine properties (isSolid, isEmitter). right now I have a 2d array of Tile Objects [MAP_WIDTH][MAP_HEIGHT].

Now I know that storing a new tile for each actual tile in the game is not necessary, but I need to find a way to store map data in a more simple format. My initial thought is storing a 2d array (or vector) of unsigned ints, but I am having trouble making this a scalable solution.

how can I represent each Tile with a number? So that in the render function I can say "Render the type of tile from the integer value stored in the array" E.G. renderTileType(map[x][y])

Sorry this is my first question, excuse me for any sins.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How many tiles do you have? It would need to be a lot for an array not to work. You can use an array of `unsigned char` rather than `int` depending on how many "tile types" you have to deal with.

Comment: It does work, but I can already see a lot of overhead. I have an array but when loading the map, I actually create a "new" Tile object for each one, but I am looking for a way to just put in some sort of identifier for each tile to tell the engine what "Type" the tile is. since I do not need the tiles to be unique, just the types. Does that make sense? I might have explained poorly, apologies

Comment: You could use the value of each 2D array element as an index into an array (vector) of unique `Tile` objects?

Comment: Wow I don't know why I couldn't think of something so simple... Thanks! I accepted an answer derived off your comment, partial credit to you.

Comment: Note that the answer provided means you'll still consume a pointer worth of memory (4 or 8 bytes usually) for each tile; whereas if you have less than 256 types of tile you could still use an `unsigned char` array as an index into a separate array. Still, whatever works. It all depends on how many tiles you actually have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just store all your unique Tiles in a single vector that doesn't need to change except during program start.  Then make a 2D array like this:

```
Tile* map[MAP_WIDTH][MAP_HEIGHT]
```

Then you can simply assign the pointers in this 2D array to point to the appropriate Tile in the `vector<Tile>`.  Lifetime of the Tiles will of course be managed by the vector, so you don't need to `new` or `delete` anything.

Comment: I initially accepted another answer, but this will be less resource intensive, and is simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What you could use is an implementation of the flyweight pattern.

So you have a 2D array of tiles.

```
Tile map[MAP_WIDTH][MAP_HEIGHT];
```

But a tile contains info about local info and a pointer off into shared info.

```
class Tile {
   // Stuff that is really shared between all tiles of the same type.
   TileImpl * impl;

   // Other stuff that varies with location in the map.
   // maybe you want to store items there, or flags, or procedures.
   ItemInfo * items;
   Flags    * flags;
   Procedures* procs;
}

// This is the stuff that all tiles of this type share.
class TileImpl {
  string imageFile;
  bool hurtsMeIfIStandOnIt;
  bool isPassable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I did this in a game server setting, I used a 2D array of pointers, and most of the pointers referred to shared Tiles (in my case it was Room* ), and my Room had a bit flag for shared vs unique. I was able to do lazy instantiation, if a player was in middle of a desert wandering, I'd instantiate a unique copy of the shared desert Room on demand as he visited each Room. Room had data structures like list of players/objects, so any rooms that had contents might also be pre-instantiated. But 99% of the map pointed to the shared Rooms which made the heap usage more efficient.

The Tile/Room also has a low cardinality enumerated type, or a simple short byte or short int that was zero based index into another array of Tile types which held detailed info like color, bitmap, rules, etc.

If array sizes become an issue, simply break your arrays into a quadrant system and do demand loading/unloading as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need a specific data structure here, that maps an integer ID with an actual Tile object.
There is the well named [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) class, or [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) if you have access to C++11 (better lookup complexity).

Just declare your array (one dimensional or two dimensional, whatever) of integer, fill it at load time, and when you need to perform actions using the actual `Tile` (collision detection, drawing etc.), simply get it from the map.

Example:

```
std::unordered_map<std::uint16_t, Tile *> tileMap;
tileMap[0] = /* get tile object for ID 0 */;
tileMap[1] = /* get tile object for ID 1 */;
…

Tile *currentTile = tileMap[idMap[x][y]]; // Here you get the tile from the ID at (x, y)
```

An other solution would be to use a `InternalTile` class, which owns every expensive resource (textures…), and pass a pointer or reference to an appropriate instance to every `Tile` object being constructed. But it is less useful as you do not use unique attribute per Tile.